# wss fails over https on apache server

Tags: php, ssl, websocket, wss

I have a server in digital ocean which is using StartCOM class I primary intermediate CA for ssl. I have set u a websocket server and I want to make a connection to  it from a page which is served by https.

When I try to connect to the websocket using just http it works fine. But when I try to use it over https by changing the websocket uri from ws to wss it does not connect.

What am I doing wrong. Connection is made using fancywebsockets.js

**fancywebsockets.js**

```
var FancyWebSocket = function(url)
{
    var callbacks = {};
    var ws_url = url;
    var conn;

    this.bind = function(event_name, callback){
        callbacks[event_name] = callbacks[event_name] || [];
        callbacks[event_name].push(callback);
        return this;// chainable
    };

    this.send = function(event_name, event_data){
        this.conn.send( event_data );
        return this;
    };

    this.connect = function() {
        if ( typeof(MozWebSocket) == 'function' )
            this.conn = new MozWebSocket(url);
        else
            this.conn = new WebSocket(url);

        // dispatch to the right handlers
        this.conn.onmessage = function(evt){
            dispatch('message', evt.data);
        };

        this.conn.onclose = function(){dispatch('close',null)}
        this.conn.onopen = function(){dispatch('open',null)}
    };

    this.disconnect = function() {
        this.conn.close();
    };

    var dispatch = function(event_name, message){
        var chain = callbacks[event_name];
        if(typeof chain == 'undefined') return; // no callbacks for this event
        for(var i = 0; i < chain.length; i++){
            chain[i]( message )
        }
    }
};
```

**Client Side JS**

```
var Server;

        function log( text ) {
        console.log(text) 
    }

        function send( text ) {
            Server.send( 'message', text );
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            log('Connecting...');
            Server = new FancyWebSocket('ws://www.myserver.com:9400');

            $('#message').keypress(function(e) {
                if ( e.keyCode == 13 && this.value ) {
                    log( 'You: ' + this.value );
                    send( this.value );


                }
            });

            //Let the user know we're connected
            Server.bind('open', function() {
                log( "Connected." );
            });

            //OH NOES! Disconnection occurred.
            Server.bind('close', function( data ) {
                log( "Disconnected." );
            });

            //Log any messages sent from server
            Server.bind('message', function( payload ) {
                log( payload );
            });

            Server.connect();
        });
```

**Server.php**

```
<?php
// prevent the server from timing out
set_time_limit(0);

// include the web sockets server script (the server is started at the far bottom of this file)
require 'class.PHPWebSocket.php';

// when a client sends data to the server
function wsOnMessage($clientID, $message, $messageLength, $binary) {
    global $Server;
    $ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

    // check if message length is 0
    if ($messageLength == 0) {
        $Server->wsClose($clientID);
        return;
    }

    //The speaker is the only person in the room. Don't let them feel lonely.
    if ( sizeof($Server->wsClients) == 1 )
        $Server->wsSend($clientID, "There isn't anyone else in the room, but I'll still listen to you. --Your Trusty Server");
    else
        //Send the message to everyone but the person who said it
        foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
            if ( $id != $clientID )
                $Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) said \"$message\"");
}

// when a client connects
function wsOnOpen($clientID)
{
    global $Server;
    $ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

    $Server->log( "$ip ($clientID) has connected." );

    //Send a join notice to everyone but the person who joined
    foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
        if ( $id != $clientID )
            $Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) has joined the room.");
}

// when a client closes or lost connection
function wsOnClose($clientID, $status) {
    global $Server;
    $ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

    $Server->log( "$ip ($clientID) has disconnected." );

    //Send a user left notice to everyone in the room
    foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
        $Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) has left the room.");
}

// start the server
$Server = new PHPWebSocket();
$Server->bind('message', 'wsOnMessage');
$Server->bind('open', 'wsOnOpen');
$Server->bind('close', 'wsOnClose');
// for other computers to connect, you will probably need to change this to your LAN IP or external IP,
// alternatively use: gethostbyaddr(gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))
$Server->wsStartServer('my.ip.add.ress', 9400);

?>
```

Server Screen Shot

[image]

It keeps on getting disconnected

Comment: Can you please provide your code?

Comment: Have you ever been able to resolve this? I am using the exact same code and changing my site to HTTPS as well.

Comment: @GillesLesire I moved to firebase which is serving my need for a realtime chat application. But I think this problem comes when you use a free SSL or when your SSL is invalid or expired.

Comment: I have a legit SSL so that is not the issue. Maybe I have to allow SSL on that specific port through my SSL config or something, I'll have to keep looking. Thanks for your response though.

Comment: Forwarding a secured port to an unsecured port using stunnels fixed the job. The only problem is that you can no longer retrieve the host IP address. It's all 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue (I even use the same PHP script) and manage to resolve this using stunnel. With a lot of trial-and-error from all kind of different, contradicting sources I managed to get it running. However you won't get client ip addresses anymore, you'll have to send it to the server manually if you need it. I read somewhere that you could forward the client IP using proxy but haven't yet been able to set that up myself.

**Install stunnel on server**

Login to your server through ssh make sure your system is fully up to date.

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Install the stunnel package

```
apt-get install stunnel4 -y
```

**Configure stunnel**

Create a config file for stunnel by running the following command

```
nano /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf
```

Write the following into the file

```
foreground = yes
key = /path/to/your/ssl/cert.key
cert =  /path/to/your/ssl/cert.pem
CAfile = /path/to/your/ssl/cert.pem
debug = 7
output = /var/log/stunnel_websocket.log

[websocket]
accept = myserver.com:9401
connect = 9400
```

Personally I just used the same certificate for the stunnel as I did for the HTTPS setup.

**Run the stunnel**

You have to keep the stunnel running like you have to keep the websocket running.
Do this with the command:

```
/etc/init.d/stunnel4 restart
```

**Alter your PHP script**

Change the PHP file server.php

```
$Server->wsStartServer('my.ip.add.ress', 9400);
```

to

```
$Server->wsStartServer('localhost', 9400);
```

**Alter the client side JS script**

```
Server = new FancyWebSocket('ws://www.myserver.com:9400');
```

should be changed to

```
Server = new FancyWebSocket('wss://www.myserver.com:9401');
```

So if you are running the stunnel and the websocket you should now be able to send and receive data over the socket again with the only difference that all clients now appear to be coming from 127.0.0.1 according to the websocket script.